# Should number of accepted answers count towards tag badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, tag-badges

Is there a reason that upvotes and downvotes count towards tag badges, but the fact that an answer is the accepted one doesn't have any weight?

The rep system gives +10 for an upvote, and +15 for an accepted answer, which appears to suggest that having something marked as accepted answer is a little more significant than an upvote. Since tag badges are meant to indicate that the user has got a good track record in this topic, it seems odd to me that votes would be taken into account for this, but accepted answers wouldn't be.

What's the thinking here? Could answer acceptance count as +1 towards tag badge score?

Comment: YES YES YES. This is important escecially for Unsung Heros (many accepted zero-scored answers).

Comment: @nicael of course I also think that "YES YES YES" in a comment should count as +3 towards my tag score :)

Comment: But accept mark means just the OP was helped. Upvotes mean *many more people* were helped. You can only earn just the one +15, but +10s keep on coming, over time.

Comment: I like the proposal, though the fact that a OP with 15+ rep would be able to contribute 2 to your score seems a *slight* problem. Accepts are basically a "vote"; they should count!

Comment: I vote no. Acceptance does *not* necessarily mean you post quality answers that are useful to future readers, or even display any particular knowledge. Acceptance frequently indicates that you solved the immediate needs of the poster.

Comment: @KenWhite nor do Upvotes. Just means its popular. In low-volume tags, including accepts may mean getting to gold in six years instead of eight. I won't wait up for that anyway. In high-volume tags, not really going to make much difference either.

Comment: If you don't think the acceptance is as important as an upvote, it could still contribute towards the badge, but get weighted less. And it seems inconsistent that it's worth more than an upvote in towards your reputation, but not worth anything towards the tag badge.