# Why is tracking next tag so outdated?

Tags: support, bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

This is a screenshot of my next tag budget for the Swift tag:

[image: Track next tag badge]

That information is incorrect, as I have [9 answers with a total score of 4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A1378388%20is%3Aa%20%5Bswift%5D) for [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).  A few answers are also accepted.  So why is that information so very outdated?  It's been since September 10 since I only had one answer on that tag.

Comment: @Mat yes that is why i meant, it was a typo and i corrected it. i have an accepted answer in swift tag

Comment: Your tag badge score depends entirely on the votes your answers have gotten.  Questions and even accepts do not contribute towards earning a tag badge.  There is a [feature request to have accepts on answers count as +1 toward the tag score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276242/4320665)  But your current progress should be `score:4, answers:8` so blame caching.

Comment: @ryanyuyu i got two upvotes on a swift question 7 days ago, and yet there is no update in my profile.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea.  On a related note, the tag score in your [tag tab on your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1378388/william-kinaan?tab=tags) also has an incorrect score of `score:2 answers:8` which might actually be a caching/update problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu exactly, i just checked there, and it doesn't have the correct information

Comment: Oh and my [first comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306113/how-does-the-budget-for-the-next-tag-work?noredirect=1#comment247264_306113) has a typo, [you have 9 answers in that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1378388%20is%3aa%20%5bswift%5d).

Comment: @ryanyuyu it is more than on week (the upvotes)

Comment: I heavily revised your question into a [meta-tag:bug] report.  If you don't agree with any of the changes, please [edit] them.  I personally find the question to be a lot clearer now.

Comment: This was [reported on Sep 9th](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305636/tag-score-is-shown-incorrectly-in-the-next-badge-tracker-section) as well. Perhaps some process somewhere is being a bit screwy?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened with me and I believe cache is to blame.
If you click on the gear icon, change the tag to be tracked to something else and then change back to track swift tag, you should see the updated figures.

Also you can see the correct numbers all the time on your profile tab under top tags sections

Comment: maybe that is correct, but i had some upvotes last week and until now they are not reflected in my profile.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Did you look at the numbers on the profile>top tags section? Are they different from the number on the tracked tag option? Also note that tag calculations are not real time but happen everyday at specific time.

Comment: yes i look and they are different, plus, it is been a week since i got my first upvotes in the swift tag