# Scheduled job to update tag score and number of answers is not being run

Tags: bug, tags, tag-badges

It has been several days since the Scheduled job is run to update my tag info.

Here is my [link to my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3345302/sagar-jain) and below is a snapshot of the tag info.
[image]

From the above total score is 22 and the number of answers is 13.

But the actual score is 36 on 19 non-wiki answers.

[image]

I would like to have the Scheduled job to run and update the tag info.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is tracking next tag so outdated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306113/why-is-tracking-next-tag-so-outdated).  That deals with the tag badge tracking instead of the profile page, but maybe it has the same root cause.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: this is about tracking a tag badge too.