# Why don't accepted answers count for anything in "Top users" maths?

Tags: discussion, tags, top-users

In the maths for "top users" of any tag, only upvotes seem to count - not number of accepted answers. For whatever reason, this seems to count really heavily against me:

[image]

My ratio of upvotes to answers is a ridiculously low 40%, yet many of those answers were accepted (with zero upvotes).

(I suspect the reason is that I tend to answer newbie questions, and newbies don't think of upvoting.)

Is there any chance the system could, say, count accepted answers as an upvote? Or even, count accepted answers as a minimum of one upvote (so 2 upvotes + accept = 2 points, 0 upvotes + accept = 1 points).

(Not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276242/should-number-of-accepted-answers-count-towards-tag-badges) question about tag *badges*.)

Comment: _"and newbies don't think of upvoting"_ - Please don't forget that users with less than 15 reputation cannot upvote.

Comment: Urgh. So many of the arbitrary rules of SO still seem so dumb, after all these years.